# Webform token for select field value (not key)

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens

I have a webform select field called `tour` and I have set up an email to go out, using the default template:

```
Submitted on [submission:date:long]
Submitted by user: [submission:user]
Submitted values are:
[submission:values]

The results of this submission may be viewed at:
[submission:url]
```

When the email goes out, it sends the `key` (nid):

```
Tour: 8349
```

rather than the `value` of the option:

```
Tour: 10-Jan-16 - Awesome Tour
```

I have tried the following tokens:

```
[submission:values:tour:label]
[submission:values:tour:value]
[submission:values:tour:withLabel]
```

I am looking for the proper token to output the value in the key/value pair of a select field.

For the `tour` field, I am replacing the options via a hook. I only mention this step for completeness sake as I don't think it has any impact on my issue.

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'FORM_ID') {

    // get all tours
    $query = db_select('node', 'n');
    $query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'));
    $query->condition('n.type', 'tour');
    $query->join('field_data_field_tour_type', 't', 't.entity_id = n.nid');
    $query->fields('t', array('field_tour_type_value'));
    $result = $query->execute();

    // group by tour type
    $options = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {

      // tour type 1
      if ($row->field_tour_type_value == 1) {
        $options['Type 1'][$row->nid] = date('d-M-y', strtotime($row->field_event_date_value)) . ': ' . $row->title;
      }

      // tour type 2
      else if ($row->field_tour_type_value == 2) {
        $options['Type 2'][$row->nid] = date('d-M-y', strtotime($row->field_event_date_value)) . ': ' . $row->title;
      }
    }

    ksort($options);

    // set the tour options correctly
    $form['submitted']['tour']['#options'] = $options;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with the form alter hook. I had updated the `#options` which made the form work just fine, however I needed to update the webform component with a line delimited list of key|value pairs.

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'FORM_ID') {

    // get all tours
    $query = db_select('node', 'n');
    $query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'));
    $query->condition('n.type', 'tour');
    $query->join('field_data_field_tour_type', 't', 't.entity_id = n.nid');
    $query->fields('t', array('field_tour_type_value'));
    $result = $query->execute();

    // group by tour type
    $options = array();
    $flat_options = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {

      // tour type 1
      if ($row->field_tour_type_value == 1) {
        $options['Type 1'][$row->nid] = date('d-M-y', strtotime($row->field_event_date_value)) . ': ' . $row->title;
        $flat_options .= $row->nid . '|' . date('d-M-y', strtotime($row->field_event_date_value)) . ': ' . $row->title . "\n";
      }

      // tour type 2
      else if ($row->field_tour_type_value == 2) {
        $options['Type 2'][$row->nid] = date('d-M-y', strtotime($row->field_event_date_value)) . ': ' . $row->title;
        $flat_options .= $row->nid . '|' . date('d-M-y', strtotime($row->field_event_date_value)) . ': ' . $row->title . "\n";
      }
    }

    ksort($options);

    // set the tour options correctly
    $form['submitted']['tour']['#options'] = $options;
    $form['#node']->webform['components'][7]['extra']['items'] = $flat_options;
  }
}
```

I've added the `$flat_options` variables to handle this and assigned it to the proper field in my form array. Keep in mind referencing the component by number `[7]` is not the cleanest and most maintainable way to do this but it works in a pinch.